# Draw tikzpicture in figure caption

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, captions

I want to make a small tikzpicture inside the caption of a figure, I namely want to create a legend of a plot in the caption. I have read section `4.9.6 Legends with \label and \ref` from the pgfplots manual. However I compile my plots to a .pdf file and then insert it in my document, so I cannot use that.

The following minimal example triggers an error `! Argument of \@caption has an extra }`

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}                                                                  
  \caption{test                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
      \draw[black] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                             
  }                                                                               
\end{figure}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see the need for boxes here, you can simply use:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}    

\newcommand\drawline[1][black]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
    \draw[#1] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}                                              
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{test \drawline[ultra thick]}
\caption{test \drawline[red,dashed]}
\end{figure}                                                                    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `\drawline` has an optional argument, LaTeX protecting mechanism is automatically used; had the definition been given as

```
\newcommand\drawline[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
    \draw[#1] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

then

```
\caption{test \drawline{ultra thick}}
```

would fail on the second run. In this case one would have to use

```
\caption{test \protect\drawline{ultra thick}}
```

or, better yet, protect the command from the definition itself:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\drawline[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
    \draw[#1] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

(Thanks to **Joseph Wright**).

Comment: I feel deflated. +1  (I should have used a stack!)

Comment: Oh wow! I also created the same command as you except for the `[1][black]` part. Indeed the error dissappears. Also thank you very much. Sorry @StevenB.Segletes but this answer suits me more.

Comment: I'm curious though, why does the answer not work if you make the argument mandatory, as in `\newcommand\drawline[1]{%` with the invocation `\caption{test \drawline{black}}`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah, I hadn't noticed that; indeed, with a mandatory argument one would need to `\protect` the `\drawline` inside `\caption`. I am also curious now. Let me see if I find the reason.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Here's the explanation (thanks to Joseph): http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19749017#19749017

Comment: Thanks for that reply.  It is the first time I've heard, where using an optional argument makes a command more robust!

Answer (score 4):

Put the `tikz` in a box, and deploy the box in the caption.  Note that by using a temporary box as in the first MWE below, it will not play well with a `\listoffigures`, but that can be circumvented by using a permanent box deployed prior to the `\listoffigures`.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                               
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}                                                                  
  \setbox0=\hbox{                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
      \draw[black] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                             
  }                                                                               
\caption{test \box0}
\end{figure}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

Thus, to use the `tikz` in the `\listoffigures`, you would need:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz}    
\newsavebox\mybox                                                           
\savebox\mybox{                                                                   
  \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
    \draw[black] (0pt,0pt) -- (15pt,0pt);                                       
  \end{tikzpicture}                                                             
}                                                                               
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[ht]                                                                
\caption{test \usebox{\mybox}}
\end{figure}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

To reply to the OP's request for a macro form, here I introduce `\prepline{length}` and `\showline` to create, and deploy the line, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                         
\usepackage{tikz} 
\def\prepline#1{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                           
      \draw[black] (0pt,0pt) -- (#1,0pt);                                       
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                             
  }    
}   
\def\showline{\box0}                                                         
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}                                                                  
\prepline{15pt}                                                                              
\caption{test \showline}
\end{figure}                                                                    
\end{document}
```

Comment: No stacks? I'm shocked! ;-)

Comment: Can this be changed to a command? I namely wanted to define a command `\newcommand{drawline}[#1]{...}`, which would then take a parameter for drawing the line, `black` for example. I would then just type `\drawline{black}` in the caption. I do not worry about the list of figures, since I have none.

Comment: @WG- Please see FOLLOW UP in revised answer.