# How to put red rectangle in the caption of a Tikz figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to put

```
\node [rectangle,draw, fill = red!70] at (2.5,-2) {};
```

in the caption of a tikz figure?

Comment: Please show us what you try so far. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225158/draw-tikzpicture-in-figure-caption can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understand you question correctly. Like this?.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}
        \center \includegraphics{example-image-a}   
        \caption{red rectangle inside caption: \protect\tikz \protect\node [rectangle,draw, fill = red!70] at (2.5,-2) {};}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]